# Issues using string::empty() with g++

Tags: c++, string, g++

I am working on a hand rolled atoi function in c++. The compiler is throwing errors when I try to use empty()

```
#include <string>
#include <cstddef>        // std::size_t
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

class Solution {
public:
    int myAtoi(std::string s) {
        int ret = 0;
        int cnt = 0;
        int neg = 1;
        
        if(empty(s))
            return 0;
        
        std::size_t found;
        std::string::iterator it=s.begin();
        if( found = s.find_first_not_of(" ") < 0)
            return 0;
        it += found;
        
        
        // code for atoi

        return ret*neg;
    }
};
```

This compiles fine in leetcode, but when I thy on my home machine with g++ I get the following error

```
myAtoi.cpp:16:12: error: ‘empty’ was not declared in this scope
   16 |         if(empty(s))
      |            ^~~~~
```

Comment: You want `s.empty()`, not `empty(s)`.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but there are no objects here, just a function. Define it on its own, not inside a class.

Answer (score 1):

The [`std::empty`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/empty)(which, due to ADL, will also work when written just like `empty(s)`, where `s` is an `std::string`) is available since C++17. So, in case of GCC, you need to specify at least the `-std=c++17` option.